# Update Linq Query For Image (File Upload)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can set true query for update? I can not get this part

```
 var image = add.Image.ToArray();
```

I must get Image Column from `UserImage`

```
            string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

            byte[] fileByte = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
            Binary binaryObj = new Binary(fileByte);

            var add = from u in db.UserImage
                          where u.User_Id == id
                          select u;

            foreach (var u in update7)
            {
                u.Image = binaryObj;
                u.ImageObj = fileName;

            }   


            db.SubmitChanges();

            var image =*add.Image*.ToArray();
            byte[] foto = (byte[])image;
            TypeConverter cc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
            Bitmap my = (Bitmap)cc.ConvertFrom(foto);

            string img = Convert.ToBase64String(foto);
            Image1.ImageUrl = string.Format("data:image/Bmp;base64,{0}", img);
```

Comment: Where have you defined `update` ?

Comment: Sql var db = new TelephoneBookDataContext();

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to update User Image. I inserted sql .I use file upload and binary

Comment: string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

                byte[] fileByte = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
                Binary binaryObj = new Binary(fileByte);

Comment: You can update our post instead of commenting on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved

```
            var add = (from u in db.UserImage
                       where u.User_Id == id
                       select u).ToList();

            foreach (var u in add)
            {
                u.Image = binaryObj;
                u.ImageObj = fileName;

            }



            db.SubmitChanges();

            var image = add[0].Image.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one? Just my 2 cents.

```
var add = from u in db.UserImage
          where u.User_Id == id
          select u;
foreach (var u in add)
{
   u.Image = binaryObj;
   u.ImageObj = fileName;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you ken. I will try tomorrow and tell you works or not.

Comment: clever, I never thought SaveChanges and SubmitChanges differ in terms of its purpose, either way, its good that "foreach(var u in add)" idea was raised. :)